# Is there a way to use mixins in Django templates like in Sass?

Tags: django, django-templates

Say I have a template with a lot of repeated code. Very simply:

```
<tr>
<td>ITEM 1</td>
<td>ITEM 2</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way in Django to create a shortcut or a mixin that allows me to define a structure and pass a variable to it? E.g.

```
{% mixin 'mymixin' %}
<td>$value</td>
{% end mixin %}
```

And then use this in the `html` such as:

```
<tr>
{% use_mixin 'mymixin' 'ITEM 1' %}
{% use_mixin 'mymixin' 'ITEM 2' %}
</tr>
```

I want to do this all in the template rather than mess about with my views so I can knock some wireframes up quickly.

Comment: See the `{% include ... %}` template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: it does, you can use `{% include 'mytemplate' with value='Item 1'%}`. In the template you render like `<td>{{ value }}</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One usually does this with the [**`{% include ... %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include). For example you can define a `td.html` template file, like:

```
<td>{{ value }}</td>
```

then in another file, you can use that file, like:

```
<tr>
    {% include 'td.html' with value='ITEM 1' %}
    {% include 'td.html' with value='ITEM 2' %}
</tr>
```

here you can thus reuse a template file in another file. It is possible to define an `{% include ... %}` tags in such template files as well, and thus construct a "hierarchy" of includes.